# failed to export application package

Tags: eclipse, export

When I updated my android sdk it gave me an error that did not let me zip align my tool, then with the sdk manager android sdk tools rev 23 and now it gives me a wayyyy more generic error, "failed to export application package" how do I solve this error? Some people suggested to check for updates, but there were no updates! can somebody tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I just re-installed eclipse, and used the same workspace, that seemed to work!